# Failed deployment on vercel through github

Tags: javascript, github, hosting, vercel

I hosted a react project on github through vercel 2 weeks ago and yesterday I tried updating the files but it kept saying failed deployment and it keeps giving me this error [failed deployment on vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udb4e.png)

I tried adding some space between the display and flex but nothing worked and when I tried updating another file I still got the same error

Comment: please post a snipper of the css, have you used a css linter to validate the css?

Comment: No I haven't here's the github tho

Comment: https://github.com/Michvista/ongoing-react-and-firebase-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css, you had the character U+00a0 multiple times which caused the parsing errors

```
.blogs-page{
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.blogs-page h1{
  color: black;
  text-align:center;
}
.form-blog-container input,
.form-blog-container textarea,
.form-blog-container label,
.form-blog-container select,
.form-blog-container button,
.form-blog-container header,
.form-blog-container p,
.form-blog-container option{
  color:black;
}
.form-blog-container option{
  background: black;
  color: white;
} 
.pop-up_box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(38, 185, 190, 0.664);
  z-index: 2;
}
.pop-up_box p,
.pop-up_box header {
  color: black;
}
.pop-up_box .pop-up{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
}
.pop-up .content{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  padding:10px;
}
.content header,
.settings ul li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.pop-up .content header{
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content header p{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  z-index: 5;
}
.content header i{
  /* Temporary border */
  padding: 20px;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.content .form-blog-container {
  margin: 15px 25px 35px;
}
.content .form-blog-container input{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}
.content .form-blog-container textarea{
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 6px;
}
.form-blog-container label{
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom:6px ;
}
.form-blog-container select{
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.content .form-blog-container :where(input, textarea){
  width:100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.content .form-blog-container .add_blog{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out ;
}
.content .form-blog-container .add_blog:hover{
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out ;
}
.pop-up_box,
.pop-up_box .pop-up{
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
.pop-up_box.show,
.pop-up_box.show .pop-up{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
.add{
  color:#222;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:transparent;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:15px;
  transition:.3s ease-in-out;
    display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
.add:hover{
  background:#222;
  color:white;
}
.categories{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: transparent;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
.cat{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
.cat:hover {
  background: black;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.cat h6:hover{
  color: white;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.cat h6{
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.categories h6{
  color: black;
}
.blogs-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100rem;
}
.blog-post{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.432), rgba(0, 5, 5, 0.7)), url('../../../public/images/church5.jpg');
  background-position:unset ;
  background-size:cover ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.blog h1,
.blog h6{
  color: white;
}
.blog h1{
  text-align: center;
}
.blog h6{
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.blog p{
text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
}
.blog h6{
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.bottom{
  display:flex;
  /* justify-content: space-evenly; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* top: 5rem; */
}
.blog .btn-blog{
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.432),rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7));
  display: flex;
  justify-self: right;
}
.btn-blog:hover{
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.blog-post i{
  font-size:15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding:5px;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index:50;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.blog-post-actions{
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.blog-post-actions button{
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .blogs{
    /* justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
    width: 20rem;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .blogs{
    width: 30rem;
  }
}
```